# Bootstrap CSS transition onhover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu, css-animations

Hi I'm trying to replicate the beautiful CSS transition dropdown menu onhover of devdojo.com (https://devdojo.com/ebook/laravelsurvivalguide) but can't replicate it. It is the onhover of the 3 dots in the main menu. Maybe I'm missing something? Thanks!

My CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu-animated {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 0.95, 1) translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0s;
    transition-property: opacity, transform, visibility;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    visibility: hidden;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.open > .dropdown-menu-animated {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class=" dropdown-toggle" href="#_" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            HOVER ME
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-animated" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/points">Sushi Points</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/points">Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Thanks @chiller .

> Updated and edited answer:

**JS**

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("open");
});

$('.dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("open");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
    color: white;
}
.dropdown-menu-animated {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 0.95, 1) translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0s;
    transition-property: opacity, transform, visibility;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    visibility: hidden;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
    /*display: none;*/
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.open > .dropdown-menu-animated {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#_" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            HOVER ME
            </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-animated" role="menu" style="color:white;background:black;">
                <li><a href="#">Bulanching</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kuya Matmat</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wedding</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Excited</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see hover in the code at all.

Comment: In that specific example it's done with javascript, not pure css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this actually done with JavaScript and all you have to do is add this jquery code in your script

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("open");
});

$('.dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("open");
});
```

and you have to remove display: none; from the class .dropdown-menu for the animation to work

[see your example here](http://www.bootply.com/zKUuDfAOpR)

you can also make it work with CSS only by adding this code:

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu-animated{

    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s, -webkit-transform .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);

}
```

[See your example with CSS only](http://www.bootply.com/UkNRmWEC0i)

Comment: you are welcome..i'm glad it helped....you can make it work with just CSS ...you can see the update on my post.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet solves your styling issue for the `:hover` appearance.
Add your transition effect in the `.dropdown .dropdown-menu-animated` rules and there you go ;)

```css
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu-animated {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: 20px;
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 0.95, 1) translate3d(0px, -15px, 0px);
    transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0s;
    transition-property: opacity, transform, visibility;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    visibility: hidden;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu-animated {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
            HOVER ME

            <ul class="dropdown-menu-animated" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="/points">Sushi Points</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/points">Two</a></li>
            </ul>            
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I've just found out that CSS only is not enough. Tried changing it hard coded in the inspect element but no animation was rendered. Thanks though. I will post that updated answer